# Validating a inputted char variable. Do-while loop will not break

Tags: java, validation, char, java.util.scanner, do-while

I have a method that checks if the user is a student, but I can't get it validate the conditions.

```
char custStud = '0';
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do{
       System.out.println("Are you a student? (Type Y or N): ");
       custStud = input.next().charAt(0);
       custStud = Character.toLowerCase(custStud);
  }
  while (custStud != 'y' || custStud != 'n');
```

When I fire up this program, it does not break the loop, even if 'y' or 'n' are entered. I suspect custStud might have accidentally changed types when changed to lowercase, but I'm not sure. 
How can I make this loop work properly?

Comment: `while (custStud != 'y' || custStud != 'n');` always going to be true

Comment: @batPerson what will happen if  N is pressed , do loop continue if user input N

Comment: @batPerson  Have a look and upvote or accept answer if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while (custStud != 'y' || custStud != 'n')` is always true, since `custStud` can't be equal to both 'y' and 'n'.

You should change the condition to:

```
while (custStud != 'y' && custStud != 'n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You've mistaken here:

```
 while (custStud != 'y' || custStud != 'n');// wrong 
 while (custStud != 'y' && custStud != 'n');// correct
```

Try running this code:

```
        char custStud = '0';
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            System.out.println("Are you a student? (Type Y or N): ");
            custStud = input.next().charAt(0);
            custStud = Character.toLowerCase(custStud);
        }
        while (custStud != 'y' && custStud != 'n');
        System.out.print("\n answer:"+custStud);
```